# When did C++ get nested classes?

Tags: c++

Somehow I never noticed until today that C++ supports nested classes.  This surprised me because when I was learning C++ back in the '90s, I specifically remember nested classes being something that Object Pascal and Java had, but which C++ did not.  I asked an old programmer friend about it and he concurred that he recalls C++ not having nested classes.

Is my recollection of C++ not having nested classes mistaken, or were they actually added to the standard at some point in the past fifteen years?  I tried searching Google for information on this topic and I haven't come up with anything helpful yet.

It could also be that I'm thinking of nested functions, which Pascal certainly supports but C does not.

Comment: Just out of interest, what's so great about nested classes?

Comment: They are magic and you can do voodoo stuff with them!

Comment: I doubt that they're "great" but if you want to have a type that is only used within a specific class, that's how you can clearly enforce and communicate that to other programmers.  They may also be of interest to language syntax geeks.

Comment: You might also be thinking of "inner" classes, which automatically own a pointer to an instance of the containing class.  Java has those, C++ does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested classes were added in [CFront 3.0](http://docs.hp.com/en/92501-90029/ch01s01.html), released in [1993](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/cfront_3_0_3.tgz/view).

**EDIT** It goes back even earlier, as you can see in the [table of contents](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/The-Annotated-C-Reference-Manual/Margaret-A-Ellis/e/9780201514599#TOC) to *The Annotated C++ Reference Manual* (1990).

Comment: 1993 brings back so many memories, but nested classes is not one of them.

Answer (score 5):

According to "A History of C++: 1979−1991" by Bjarne Stroustrup

> Later, after many technical problems
>   and much discontent from users, nested
>   class scopes were re−introduced into
>   C++ in 1989 [Ellis,1990].

see page 28 in http://www.research.att.com/~bs/hopl2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> were they actually added to the
>   standard at some point in the past
>   fifteen years?

C++ was first standardised in [1998](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CCAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-d0.fnal.gov%2F~dladams%2Fcxx_standard.pdf&ei=zQkHTP6qA4mvcI7D0PsN&usg=AFQjCNFLQrmMbJ_YDTJ1OgD1KjkqgX_vQA&sig2=qE_nXPnExjEdt_OV0iCz7w) and this standard included nested classes in section 9.7. Since your talking early 90s in your question it is quite possible that whatever particular compiler you were using at the time did not provide support for them.

So Nested Classe were officially supported from 1998 onwards but could have been available (depending on your compiler) at any time prior to this, as alluded to in the answer from Ken Bloom.